# how to enable sound when autoplay is set in facebook embedded video?

Tags: facebook, audio, video

I embedded a video from facebook in my website and i set it in autoplay, but the sound is muted unless you click the volume and it will play the sound.

Comment: That seems to be rather a good thing, from a user perspective. Many people will just get annoyed if pages the opened perhaps in a background tab start pestering them with sound without asking.

Answer (score 21):

Just add `&mute=0` to the iframe url.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2F.....&height=280&mute=0" width="500" height="280" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: That does not work when autoplay=1 is added to the url.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually use [Facebook Embedded Video Player API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api) to control your embedded video in your website, such as unmuting it on page load.

Take note that this doesn't work on embedding videos thru `<iframe>` tag. Use the `<div>` tag as mentioned in the link (or see sample below).

Here's a sample script I got from the link, with insertion of `my_video_player.unmute()` on `xfbml.ready` event. Make sure you provide the proper `FB appId`.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '{your-app-id}',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
      });

      // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance
      var my_video_player;
      FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
        if (msg.type === 'video') {
          my_video_player = msg.instance;
          my_video_player.unmute();
        }
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

  <!-- Your embedded video player code -->
  <div  
    class="fb-video" 
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" 
    data-width="500" 
    data-autoplay="true"
    data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The 'xfbml.ready' is not fired for live videos, which means we get no access to video player instance.