# Unmute facebook live video

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently trying to embed a facebook live video that will auto play with the audio unmuted.  I've tried to use the solution [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584472/how-to-enable-sound-when-autoplay-is-set-in-facebook-embedded-video)  however it does not seem to work on live videos as the xfbml.ready event does not seem to get called.

Has anybody figured out a way to enable the audio on a live embedded video?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is, that you shouldn't use autoplay and then unmute, rather normally embed the video, then start it by `msg.instance.play()`.

See the code below, or try this link: http://shoepimper.com/fb.html

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '{your-app-id}',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
      });

      // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance
      FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
        if (msg.type === 'video') {
          msg.instance.play();
        }
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

  <!-- Your embedded video player code -->
  <div  
    class="fb-video" 
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/GoSportsLive/videos/vb.1481996068797424/1779032592427102/" 
    data-width="500" 
    data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
```

Comment: Even with your solution the "xfbml.ready" is not fired at all. Which means you cannot get the instance of video player. As the original poster said the event is not fired only for live videos. Normal uploaded videos and VOD fire this event just fine.

Comment: I see, unfortunately this is still an issue for live video.

Comment: What I am wondering is, if this is an intended behavior from facebook or something they plan to fix. It's been a while this problem has been around. Is there a way we can let facebook developers know about this. I posted the issue in their support page but it did not look like a page for developer issues.